# Pass each part of a list in a variable in Python?

Tags: python, immutability

i have this code where searches a main folder for subfolders that contain a certain file extension and open it in Python.

```
rootdir = '/path/to/dir' # path to your root directory you walk
sfiles = [] # a list with all the .shp files
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath): # Get all files in the subdirectories
            if file.endswith('.shp'): # If it's an .shp.
                filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                sfiles.append(filepath)
                fiona.open(filepath)
```

now try to assign it

```
a=sfiles[0]
a.schema #method 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'schema'
```

Comment: What is the question? How is the code related to the question title? And how is the *immutability* tag relevant? Currently this questions looks *unclear*...

Comment: The code shows how i access each file by storing it in a list. the question is how do i store each element from the list in  a variable to apply a method in it.The last part shows what i want to do and the error that gives. immutabilty is maybe th reason that i cant assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a method you need to use paranthesis like so:

```
a.schema()
```

The error message you got is correct:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'schema'
```

The thing you append to *sfiles* are just strings and strings do not contain a attribute called 'schema' or a method with this name for that matter.

Perhaps you want to add file handles instead of paths?

```
sfiles.append(fiona.open(filepath))
```

Then again it's not a good idea to have so many files opened at once.
Maybe find the files as you are doing now and the open one file at once in a later loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
filesList = list()
extension = "*.shp"
rootdir = '/path/to/dir'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
     for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, extension):
             #filesList.append(os.path.join(path, name)) 
             with open(os.path.join(path, name), 'r') as fp:
                   #write your own logic here.
```

If you want to append in list and want to use the same in further code then use:

```
filesList.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

else you can directly use:

```
with open(os.path.join(path, name), 'r') as fp:
```

try:

```
a=sfiles[0]
a.schema()
```

#schema is a method that might be the reason you were getting error because you have missed "()".